# Edges running on top of each other in mxGraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am setting up the mxGraph like this:

```
model = new mxGraphModel();
    // Tell the model to manage cell ids for us
    model.isCreateIds();

    graph = new mxGraph(container, model);        

    var graphMgr = new GraphManager(graph);
    var edgeMgr = new EdgeManager();

    // Configure mxGraph properties, methods, and event handlers
    graphMgr.configure();

    // Create style sheet
    graphMgr.defineStyles();

    // Initialize the layout managers
    graphMgr.defineLayout(model);

    // Get the main parent for the graph
    var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
    var parallelEdges = new mxParallelEdgeLayout(graph);
    parallelEdges.execute(parent);
```

That is the initial setup. I just added the `mxParallelEdgeLayout` thing because I have found that that is supposed to prevent edges from running on top of each other and overlap. What I mean by overlapping and running on top of each other:

[image]

I am using Orthogonal edge styling.

If this is not how you prevent this (using mxParallelEdgeLayout), then is there a way that mxGraph prevents this kind of thing? And if mxParallelEdgeLayout is the way to go, does anyone know why it is not accepting my execution of the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the *spacing* variable?

```
var parallelEdges = new mxParallelEdgeLayout(graph);
parallelEdges.spacing = 20;
```